# Unresolved "size" in vector of vectors using operator[] in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use Eclipse CDT (just for the 'organize includes' functionality) on OS X for a C++ project.  The static analyzer (syntax highlighting) doesn't seem to be able to resolve the type of a template operator overload in container classes, such as std::vector and operator[].  Example:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > st = {{0}};

  st[0].size(); // Method 'size' could not be resolved
  st.front().size(); // no problem
}
```

This code compiles in g++ and clang++.  I am not excited about turning off syntax highlighting completely (what's the point of the IDE?).  Any ideas on getting Eclipse CDT (specifically Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) on OS X) to understand this?

EDIT: Updated with a simpler MWE, the problem was not related to using a struct.

EDIT: Added Eclipse CDT version.

Comment: Is this an actual compilation error or a CDT error ?  If CDT it's not the best at this.  I ended up turning CDT highlighting off.

Comment: To me the code is fine. Unrelated: suggestion: don't use all capital identifiers.

Comment: Another unrelated suggestion: don't use `typedef struct` in C++. `struct st { int i; };` would be just fine.

Comment: I don't have access to a Mac at the moment to test this, but I have tried this on all versions of Eclipse for the last 5 years, g++ 4.8/5/6 and clang++ 4 (on Linux 64-bit) and all of them work. Can you provide an error report with your versions please? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT

Comment: @MichaelWalz true, I was trying to make it very clear.  Updated, don't want to be a bad influence.

Comment: @zett42 Good point, it is an artifact of the old C project I am converting to C++.  However, the problem is unrelated to structs, as I've updated the MWE to show.

Comment: @JonahGraham I have reported the bug.  It seems this was an issue with past builds on other OSes, but was marked as fixed.

Comment: @Rakurai Thanks for reporting the bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518465 Can you add the version of XCode or where you are getting the compiler and libstdc++ from (on the bug)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is not compiling your code every time you type something new but it uses a tool for static StaticAnalysis. Unfortunately that tool is not perfect and things like this happen.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis

Comment: I don't think that trying to access an STL container of STL containers by operator[] is really unusual, so this kind of problem moves the tool from 'not perfect' to 'practically unusable' in my opinion.  I hope it becomes a nonissue in the future, some of the features of Eclipse CDT look very handy.